# Unable to mount hard-disk at startup

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, 14.04

I am trying to mount a separate hard-disk automatically before startup, and for some reason fstab is failing me. It will not boot the partition on a separate disk at startup. The partition is question is in the last entry.

This is my present entry

```
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=974b76b1-0d50-44af-9907-9d4a7eb5dafa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdc5 during installation
UUID=147dedf1-4f84-4c1f-87e9-662c51372e21 none            swap    sw              0       0

#data partition
UUID=a14cb5de-4a9f-44bb-a59f-63c2dedc4950 /mnt/Data ext4 uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

I am able to mount the device with
    sudo /dev/sdc6 /mnt/Data

I am using the disk as my data drive while the OS runs on an SSD. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything helpful in `dmesg`?

Comment: @Jos '[    4.928704] EXT4-fs (sdc6): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value' but id -u rewarp gives 1000.

Comment: As a workaround I added the mount command to /etc/rc.local which works rather neatly. But I still want to do it the "proper" way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue by issuing the default options for fstab with some minor tweaks.

Instead of

```
UUID=a14cb5de-4a9f-44bb-a59f-63c2dedc4950 /mnt/Data ext4 uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

I instead went with the defaults with the exception of `nosuid` and `nodev` for `suid` and `nodev`

```
UUID=a14cb5de-4a9f-44bb-a59f-63c2dedc4950 /mnt/Data auto rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,auto,nouser,async 0 0
```

The 'dmesg' output did give a hint that it was a user issue. I guess the user isn't loaded yet into the system so that's why the gid wasn't recognised? Anyway, thanks Jos for the hint that led to me resolving the issue.